# RSS Library 'feed4j' .getPubDate() give 'null'

Tags: java, rss, feed, reader

I'm trying to do an RSS Reader using the feed4j library and i write this simple code:

```
import java.net.URL;

import it.sauronsoftware.feed4j.FeedParser;
import it.sauronsoftware.feed4j.bean.Feed;
import it.sauronsoftware.feed4j.bean.FeedHeader;
import it.sauronsoftware.feed4j.bean.FeedItem;
import javax.swing.*;

public class LettoreRSS{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        URL url = new URL("myxmlurl");
        Feed feed = FeedParser.parse(url);
        int items = feed.getItemCount();
        FeedHeader header = feed.getHeader();
        int dim=50;

        JFrame frm = new JFrame(header.getTitle()+" - Last News");
        frm.setResizable(false);
        frm.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        frm.setBounds(10, 10, 600, 600);
        frm.setVisible(true);
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        for (int i=0;i<items;i++)
        {
            FeedItem item = feed.getItem(i);
            JLabel label = new JLabel();
            label.setBounds(0, dim*i, 600, 50);
            label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            label.setText(item.getTitle()+"   "+item.getPubDate());
            frm.add(label);
        }

    }
}
```

But there is a problem: when i start the progrm he write the title but the puDate is 'null' for all (i try to write a label for the header (FeedHeader header) and the header.getPubDate() give th i solve? Thnak you!e date correctly. It is the same for some xml that i try.
How can i solve?
Thank you!

Comment: What feeds are you using? Are you sure that the items have pubDates? Try http://channel9.msdn.com/Feeds/RSS it has pubDates on items

Comment: one the xml that i use is this and he has the pubDate http://sarrocchi.it/backend.php for the header the pubDate works, but for items it give always null

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I found that it's because of date format defined in [it.sauronsoftware.feed4j.Constants.java](https://github.com/icyleaf/feed4j/blob/master/src/it/sauronsoftware/feed4j/Constants.java) which was wrong for my feeds. so I implement my own method for getting date. like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < feedItem.getNodeCount(); i++) {
            RawNode node = feedItem.getNode(i);
            if (node instanceof RawElement) {
                RawElement element = (RawElement) node;
                String name = element.getName();
                String value = element.getValue();
                if (value == null) {
                    return null;
                }
                if (name.equals(FEED_DATE_TAG)) {
                    try {
                        return new SimpleDateFormat(FEED_DATE_FORMAT, Locale.US).parse(value);
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        logger.error("could not parse date : {} ", e.getMessage());
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

feed4j date formatter is:  public DateFormat RFC_822_DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "EEE', 'dd' 'MMM' 'yyyy' 'HH:mm:ss' 'z", Locale.US);

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, but I found it's just a stupid bug in the code that handles RSS 2.0. If you look in feed4j's source code in TypeRSS_2_0.java, you'll see in the handleItem method that it completely forgets to handle pubDate.

This is easy it fix. Just add the following to the series of if-else statements (right below the one for guid - about line 179) and recompile the feed4j.jar file.

```
else if (ename.equals("pubDate")) {
   try {
      item.setPubDate(Constants.RFC_822_DATE_FORMAT.parse(evalue));
   } catch (ParseException e) {
       ;
   }
```